# Twitter API returns invalid callback - Cannot authorize

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

[SOLVED, but I'm open to new suggestions...]

I'm integrating Twitter into my Android app using twitter4j.

When I try to authorize with Twitter, I am calling the following endpoint with my oauth token:

`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN`

which **should** redirect me to:

`MY-CALLBACK:///?oauth_token=***&oauth_verifier=***`

but instead, it redirects me to:

`https://api.twitter.comMY-CALLBACK///?oauth_token=***&oauth_verifier=***`

which is obviously not a valid url.
(Also, the `:` is missing - it should be `MY-CALLBACK:///...`)

Please note I'm using WebView for my calls


I could manipulate this string to make everything work, but there has to be a better way...



I am passing my callback URL to

`getOAuthRequestToken("MY-CALLBACK:///");`

and have already set the intent-filter for my activity with

`<data android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />`

Also, the activity has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`



What am I doing wrong?


[edit:more details]

```
mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

twitterWebView = new WebView(ActivityTwitterAuthorize.this);

twitterWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith(Constants.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

        // HACKY PART!
        // I added the following code to force it to work, but this is a dirty hack...
        // String TWITTER_CALLBACK_INVALID_PREFIX = "https://api.twitter.comx-oauthflow-twitter///";
        // TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "MY-CALLBACK:///";
        // BEGIN
        } else if (url.startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_INVALID_PREFIX)) {
            url = url.substring(TWITTER_CALLBACK_INVALID_PREFIX.length());
            url = Constants.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL + url;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        // END

        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }

});

mTwitterReqToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);

twitterWebView.loadUrl(mTwitterReqToken.getAuthenticationURL());
```

WITHOUT the hacky part, this code results in "Webpage not available" error, because the url is invalid:

`https://api.twitter.comMY-CALLBACK///?oauth_token=***&oauth_verifier=***`

If the url was `MY-CALLBACK:///?oauth_token=***&oauth_verifier=***` then my activity would receive an Intent, and everything would be ok...

WITH the "hacky part", my code works, but I would like to avoid that piece of code.

Comment: Please Give More Details, I Don't Understand your Problem.

Comment: you need to close webView dialog after getting if (url.startsWith(Constants.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL))  condition.

Comment: I tried that, too, but even when I type `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN` in my browser, the Twitter api returns invalid url...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found I just could not get it to work this way after following the guides I've seen online.

I ended up using my own custom `WebViewClient` with the code:

```
if ( url.contains( "MY-CALLBACK:///" ) )
{
    final int start = url.indexOf( '?' ) + 1;
    final String params = url.substring( start );
    final String verifierToken = "oauth_verifier=";
    if ( params.contains( verifierToken ) )
    {
        final int value = params.indexOf( verifierToken ) + verifierToken.length();
        final String token = params.substring( value );
        view.stopLoading();                  
        authoriseNewUser( token );
    }
    else if ( params.contains( "denied" ) )
    {
        view.stopLoading();
        finish();
    }
}
else
{
    view.loadUrl( url );
}
return true;
```

Comment: That's basically what I did, too (check for existence of my callback url inside the returned url, and modify it to match my expected format), but is there a better way?

Comment: Actually, I think I'll rework my code to use something like this instead of broadcasting Intents... This is far more efficient! If no one offers a better solution, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution, I removed the intent-filter altogether! Just a suggestion for you, for extracting query parameters from your string, you could use `Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); String oAuthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier"); if (oAuthVerifier != null) {...}` It looks nicer then the url.substring() thing... Thanks!

Comment: @ScouseChris could you say you've placed this code where?

Comment: @Afflatus I added that check in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Answer (score 0):

Use Below CallBack_URI for that, it may help you.

```
public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
public static final String  CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
```

Comment: No, that's not the point. It is perfectly ok to use just OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + ":///"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "litestcalback";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME+ "://" +OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
```

use this type of callback_url in code and manifest file...

Comment: This is the third answer that says my callback url is wrong. No, my callback url is not wrong. I already tried this and it's the same whether I use SCHEME://HOST or just SCHEME:///

Comment: I tried `public static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter:///";` and I also tried `public static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://callback";`. Doesn't matter, it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: try this dear. private static final Uri CALLBACK_URI = Uri.parse("twifj://twitterfj"); and in your custom WebViewClient   if (url.startsWith(CALLBACK_URI.toString())) {}

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but this doesn't help me. The url returned from server simply does NOT start with my callback uri. It starts with `https://api.twitter.com` and then my callback uri

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is nothing wrong with your code. I was getting the same result yesterday, but today it works like a charm. It is probably a server side issue. Could you try again your original (with no hacky part) solution, pls?

Comment: I guessed that was the server-side issue. I included code for dealing with both cases, just to be on the safe side. I write to log when the "hacky" part is executed, so I will check that. I will let you know these days...